# Домен на другом сервере

Tags: linux, сервер, dns, домен

Есть у меня выделенный IP адрес, и есть 2 веб-сервера. Соответственно по IP адресу мы попадаем на роутер, где стоит переадресация 80 порта на **сервер1**.

И есть у меня 2 домена на этот IP адрес. Соответственно заходим на **домен1.ру** и попадаем на **сервер1**, заходим на **домен2.ру** попадаем тоже на **сервер1**.

Мне же надо настроить, чтобы открывая **домен2.ру** пользователь попадал на **сервер2**. На **сервере1** стоит debian, на **сервере2** стоит ubuntu.

Что мне надо поставить/настроить на **сервере1**, чтобы пользователь заходя на **домен2.ру** попадал на **сервер2**, буду рад за ссылки на какие либо статьи, просто я даже не знаю что искать.

P.S роутер Asus RT-N16

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Если на **сервере1** стоит Apache, то всё просто: нужно использовать [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Но стоит обратить внимание, что трафик весь пойдет через **сервер1** на **сервер2**.

Ссылка для прочтения:

1. [Не полностью переведенная статья](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/portfolio/mod_proxy.html)
2. [Хорошая шпаргалка](http://sadmin.pp.ua/reverse-proxy-apache-mod_proxy.html)

Comment: Спасибо! А есть еще какие-нибудь варианты решения? Чтобы не только апач можно использовать. Я смотрел в сторону своего днс сервера, но так и не понял оно это или нет

Comment: На nginx тоже можно это сделать. DNS вам не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Ставите nginx и...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    example1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server1;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    example2.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Опять же, если я хочу не только к веб-серверу попасть, но и через ssh зайти на этот сервер, то этот вариант не поможет

Comment: SSH на одном сервере может подключиться к другому. Либо вы пробрасываете другой порт для SSH второго сервера. Кстати использовать нестандартные порты для SSH подключения еще и более безопасно!